# .htaccess rewrite rule puzzle

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

Because I need to password protect a subdirectory using cPanel, I modified Wordpress's .htaccess rule as instructed here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess

This is my current wordpress rewrite block:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Notice particularly this line:

```
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
```

The normal wordpress Rewrite Rule is this:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

It works perfectly for the password-protected directory. But I seem to have lost the rewrite for when a page gets loaded without the trailing slash.

Before I changed this, Wordpress would look at a url like this:
`http://example.com/about-us` and load it up as `http://example.com/about-us/` (with a trailing slash).

Now it simply goes to a Not Found page. It's not even loading the theme's 404 page.

Any ideas how to fix this without mucking up my password-protected directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [question mark](http://regular-expressions.mobi/optional.html):

```
RewriteRule ./?$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: That does fix the trailing slash Not Found error. But now the password-protected directory is not working again. :(